# In spades, is a deuce of clubs considered a spade?

Tags: variants, spades

In Spades, is a deuce of clubs/hearts considered a spade?  I played with some people that argued they consider their suit to be spade.

Comment: Why would it be considered a spade? As far as I am aware it can't take a trick unless everyone is out of both clubs and spades and depending on the rules the 2 of clubs should be the first card played so that will never happen.

Comment: @JoeW, the rule: "2 of clubs should be the first card played".  is a Hearts rule, it is not common in Spades.

Comment: @Cohensius Yes and I did say it was depending on the rules that it was played first and I mentioned that as a side note as in some cases it will be the first card played.

Answer (score 10):

The deuce of club and hearts do not considered a spade in the **standard game,** however there are variants where they do.

From [Pagat](https://www.pagat.com/auctionwhist/spades.html):

> In some versions of Spades, some or all of the four **twos are elevated to the top of the spade suit**, are ranked in some specified order, and are considered to be spades. The rest of the cards rank as in normal.

For example, in the *New York City rules* the trump suit ranks is as follows: `big joker, small joker, 2♦, 2♠, A, K, Q, J, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3`

In the *Deuces high* rules the trump suit is is as follows:`2♠, 2♦, 2♣ 2♡, A, K, Q, J, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3`

Those variants are pretty common, and are implemented for example at AI-factory's [Spades free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.aifactory.spadesfree&hl=en&pli=1) app.

Answer (score 1):

Like any game, Spades has a lot of variations. Long unnecessary story short, I've moved A LOT. 48 states, 6 provinces, dozens of cities in Mexico...
I like to play cards, it seems to dissolve borders. Anyway...

When I learned to play as a kid in Syracuse NY.  Rank of cards from highest to lowest was:
Big Joker, Little Joker, 2 H, 2 C, 2 D, 2 S, A S, --- 3 S.
3 H, and 3 C weren't used.
Total number of tricks remained the same, but total number of spades was 18 instead of 13.

Since then, I've played a bunch of variations from "no nil bid allowed" "max 5 bid/hand" "reneg" "forced blind when -200" "2 D, and 2 S were trump behind the jokers" "jokers high then A S --- 2 S" and any number of combinations of these rules.

The "original" rules without the jokers and only the 13 spades as trump is probably the most common across the US as a whole. Maybe not the way they'd usually play, but they're familiar with this way most often.

Apples and Oranges, though.  They're really different games.  The mechanics are different, the tracking becomes a little more challenging, and the game seems to be less predictable.  Just like with Hearts, spades gets to be a little mechanical and repetitious, but the additional 5 trump cards make it a little less so.

Best practice with any game is to make sure you all know the rules BEFORE the situation presents itself unless you're all very patient :-)